# Firebase Realtime Database Android Studio: Why is .orderByValue() not working?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im developing an application android studio with Java code. I have a model class TimeModel
with properties String startTimes, endTime;

I want to store start- and endTimes in Firebase as a String and retrieve data later.

Firebase looks like this:

[image]

The code in java:

```
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
userID = firebaseUser.getUid();


databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
//Storing data Timemodel.startTime:

timesModel = new TimesModel(startTimeConverted, "null");
databaseReference.child(userID).child("TIMES").push().setValue(timesModel);
```

Retrieving Data:

```
Query query = databaseReference.child(userID).child("TIMES").child("start").orderByValue();
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            TimesModel timesModel1 = postSnapshot.getValue(TimesModel.class);
            textViewone.setText(timesModel1.start);
        }

    }
```

The problem is the `orderByValue()` Method: in the description from Google it says that:

> When using orderByValue(), children are ordered by their value. The ordering criteria are the same as in orderByChild(), except the value of the node is used instead of the value of a specified child key.

Why is the code not working to show me in the textview the startTime of TimeModel?

I tried queries with methods orderByKey(), orderByChild() and they all work like intended.

If i use orderByValue nothing is shown.

What exactly is value here? If i use this code:

```
Query query = databaseReference.child(userID).child("TIMES").orderByValue();
```

Its showing me a time in the textview. but i cannot progress with sorting mewthods like
.equalsTo() etc....
I dont get the point which value is here taken by the method.

Maybe some experienced FirebaseUser can help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't match your data model:

```
Query query = databaseReference.child(userID).child("TIMES").child("start").orderByValue()
```

In text:

1. You create a reference to `/$uid/TIMES`.
2. Then you create a reference to the `start` child under there.
3. Then you order each child node on its value.

The problem is in step 2: since there is no data under `/$uid/TIMES/start` in your database, you get no results.

If you want to order the child nodes under `/$uid/TIMES` on the value in their `start` property, that'd be:

```
Query query = databaseReference.child(userID).child("TIMES").orderByChild("start")
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I dont understand what you say in step 2. The time "2023-05..." next to startTime (/$uid/TIMES/start) is the data, or not? For what is orderByValue() then used for?

Comment: Order by value is if you have a list of child nodes each with a single value: `parent: { child1: 1, child2: 2, child3: 3 }`. --- Did you give `orderByChild` a try as I showed in my answer? Did it work?

Comment: Hello, yes i did it already with orderByChild. I think i understand now better what orderByValue is used for. Is it correct, that if i use: Query query = databaseReference.child(userID).child("TIMES").orderByValue() everything gets sorted because "Times" has the unique childs with the keys. And then the keys are the value? Because if i do this it shows the same Date as if i use child("TIMES").orderByChild(start) or child("TIMES").orderByKey().

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you're asking there and the code becomes hard to read in a comment like that. If you can't get the code from my answer to work, edit your question to add an update to show where you got stuck.

Comment: @steeveKA1 Any update here?